# MySQL + PHP: General Help Needed for Echoing Data from Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables (Users, Wall). The UserID in the Wall table is a foreign key. How would I go about fetching the users details using this? (I want to fetch the users Forename and Surname who posted the message.)

Users Table:
[alt text http://i33.tinypic.com/1eq6n5.png](http://i33.tinypic.com/1eq6n5.png)

Wall Table:
[alt text http://i37.tinypic.com/b5po5u.png](http://i37.tinypic.com/b5po5u.png)

EDIT: I cannot figure out how to show the data.

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alpha</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />  
    </head>
    <body>

<?php 

// Logged IN
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Email'])) {


// Post to Database
if(!empty($_POST['message']))
{
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
$postmessage = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Wall (Message, UserID) VALUES('".$message."', '".$_SESSION['UserID']."')");
}

// Collet Latest Posts

$result = mysql_query('SELECT Message, UserID 
                         FROM Wall 
                     ORDER BY MessageID DESC 
                        LIMIT 20') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

// Collet Post User

$query = mysql_query('SELECT Forename, Surname FROM Users INNER JOIN Wall ON Users.UserID = Wall.UserID;') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

    ?>
    <div id ="container">
        <div id="insideleft">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.php">Edit Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="wall.php">Community Wall</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="insideright">
            <h1>Community Wall</h1>
            <br />
            <form method="post" action="wall.php" name="wallpost" id="wallpost">
                <label for="message" class="message">Message: </label> <input type="text" name="message" id="message" class="message"/>
                <input type="submit" name="messagesub" id="messagesub" value="Post" /><br /><br />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <p></p>
            <p><?=stripslashes($row['Message'])?></p><br />

<?php
} ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

//else {echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;index.php'>";}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I am outputting the message but I have no idea how to output the Forename and Surname of the poster.